# How to sort numbers in the first row then in the second one and finally in the third one in the ascending order but saving the columns order?

Tags: arrays, sorting, apex-code, apex

How to sort numbers in the first row then in the second one and finally in the third one in the ascending order by their columns values. For, example, I have the following array:

```
  7 |10 |15 | 7 | 7
  5 | 0 | 4 | 3 | 3
  1 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 4
```

Then I need to transform it by sorting the first row but saving the columns order:

```
 7 | 7 | 7 |10 |15
 5 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 4
 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 | 3
```

On the second iteration I should get something like this:

```
 7 | 7 | 7 |10 |15
 3 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 4
 4 | 2 | 1 | 4 | 3
```

And, at the end:

```
 7 | 7 | 7 |10 |15
 3 | 3 | 5 | 0 | 4
 2 | 4 | 1 | 4 | 3
```

I have the following code that sorts the first row and saving the columns order:

```
  Integer k = column.size() - 1;
  while (k > 1) {
    Integer id = 0;
    for (Integer j = 1; j <= k; j++)
      if (listWithNumbers[0][j] > listWithNumbers[0][id])
        id = j;
      for (Integer i = 0; i < listWithNumbers.size(); i++) {
        Integer max = listWithNumbers[i][id];
        listWithNumbers[i][id] = listWithNumbers[i][k];
        listWithNumbers[i][k] = max;
      }
  k -= 1;
}
```

And, I tried to rewrite the same code for sorting the second row but it doesn't sort correctly:

```
k = column.size() - 1;
while (k > 1) {
  Integer id = 0;
    for (Integer j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
        if (listWithNumbers[0][j-1] == listWithNumbers[0][j])
          id = j-1;
      for (Integer i = 1; i < listWithNumbers.size(); i++) {
        Integer max = listWithNumbers[i][id];
        listWithNumbers[i][id] = listWithNumbers[i][k];
        listWithNumbers[i][k] = max;
      }    
    }        
  k -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Your final state does not appeared to sorted, as viewed from any direction (up or down).  Did you mis copy some data?

Comment: You do not need to have multiple iterations, just create a single `Comparator` that checks first row, than is the same checks the second, and so on...

Comment: It might be easier to transform the array to something like a `List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>`, where the first Integer is the value and the second Integer is the original index.  Then sort the list by value.  Then iterate and use the original index from the Pair to swap within the next list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need to have multiple iterations, EG do not have to print out the steps, then just create a single `Comparator` that checks first row, then if the same checks the second, and so on...

Something like this:

```
public Comparator<Number[]> comp = (Number[] a, Number[] b) ->
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i )
    if ( !a[i].equals( b[i] ) )
      return a[i].compareTo( b[i] );
  return 0;
}
```